# How to always make a copy for an affectation?

Tags: arrays, module, matrix, reference, ocaml

I have defined a `Matrix` module as follows:

```
module Matrix =
  struct
    type 'a matrix = 'a array array

    let make (nr: int) (nc: int) (init: 'a) : 'a matrix =
      let result = Array.make nr (Array.make nc init) in
      for i = 0 to nr - 1 do
        result.(i) <- Array.make nc init
      done;
      result

    let copy (m: 'a matrix) : 'a matrix =
      let l = nbrows m in
      if l = 0 then m else
        let result = Array.make l m.(0) in
        for i = 0 to l - 1 do
          result.(i) <- Array.copy m.(i) 
        done;
        result

    ...
```

Then I could code for instance `let mat = Matrix.make 5 5 100`. The advantage of defining `Matrix` module is to hide the type of its components. For example, I may later want to define a matrix with `'a list list` or with `map`. I will just need to change this module, but not the code who uses this module.

But one problem I realize is that, if I do `let m1 = m0 in ...`, `m1` and `m0` will share a same physical item: any change to `m1` will affect `m0`. Actually this is the purpose of the `copy` function. But is there a way to let the module always call `copy` for an `affectation`?

The worse is for a function `let f (m: 'a matrix) = ...`, any change inside `f` to `m` will affect the outer parameter who past its value to `m`. Is there a way to avoid `f` to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `let m1 = m0`, the names `m1` and `m0` denote the same object. This is not an assignment, it is a binding of a value to a name. Since the expression after the `=` sign is a simple name, both names `m1` and `m0` have the same value bound to them.

If you want to make a copy of a mutable data structure, you must request that copy explicitly.

If you want to be able to pass data around without having to modify it, this data must be immutable. This, indeed, is a key reason to use immutable data. When you use mutable data, you need to think carefully about sharing between data structures and who is responsible for copying when needed.

While you can reorganize any data structure to be immutable, dense matrices are not an example where immutability shines, because immutable representations of dense matrices tend to require rather more memory and more processing time.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily define shadow copies, something along:

```
type 'a m =
  | Shared of 'a matrix
  | Matrix of 'a array array

and 'a matrix = {
  mutable m : 'a m;
}

let copy_matrix m = [... YOUR CODE FOR COPY ...]

(* Shadow copy *)
let copy matrix =
  { m = Shared matrix }

let rec content m =
  match m.m with
    | Shared m -> content m
    | Matrix m -> m

let write m x y k =
  let c = match m.m with
    | Shared matrix ->
      (* Break the shared chain & copy the initial shared matrix *)
      let c = copy_matrix (content matrix) in
      m.m <- Matrix c;
      c
    | Matrix m -> m in
  c.(x).(y) <- k
```

Comment: you use `copy` when you want to copy a matrix. You use `write m x y k` when you want to modify field the field (x,y) of matri m, ie. when you want to do `m.(x).(y) <- k`